# Form filtered date results returning both dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Have MS Access form that has 2 date fields and an amount field.

The idea is to allow the user to apply a filter to the form to filter results between 2 dates and above a certain amount.  However the results are inconsistent, and it tends to list both dates that are in the `mm/dd/yyyy` and the `dd/mm/yyyy` format in results.  Where I only want `dd/mm/yyyy` which is what the short date and system dates are set to.

```
strCriteria = 
            "([Order Date] >= #" & Me.txtOrderDateFrom & "# 
                AND [Order Date] <= #" & Me.txtOrderDateTo & "# 
                And [Order Amount]>= " & (CLng(Me.txtSumOfLinePrice)) & ")"

task = "select * from OrderListQ where (" & strCriteria & ") order by [order date]"

DoCmd.ApplyFilter task
```

Answer (score 0):

You must apply a proper format for the string expressions of the date values:

```
strCriteria = "[Order Date] >= #" & Format(Me!txtOrderDateFrom.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND [Order Date] <= #" & Format(Me!txtOrderDateTo.Value, yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And [Order Amount] >= " & Str(Me!txtSumOfLinePrice.Value) & ""
```

Comment: I would like to point out Gustav that you are using localized expressions  also.   the difference is that databases can interpret medium or long localised formats better than short formats.

Comment: No, `yyyy\/mm\/dd` returns digits only, and the backslash escapes the slash to force a slash in the output and not the localized date separator which a slash only will return, thus this expression will never be localized. Further, the ISO sequence _yyyy-mm-dd_ is unambiguous, so - and finally - it is not correct that a long or any other format is understood "better"; it will _always_ be understood correctly, thus there is no "better" format.

Comment: the digits only are not guaranteed to work if you have differences in date formats in data base to application  -  Any format returns a string only and US dates cause issues with dates used in other areas such as Europe and the UK for example

Comment: This is not correct. The digits-only format in ISO sequence is _the only format_ guaranteed to work in any environment in any scenario. The "reverse" US format, mm/dd/yyyy, will work for SQL but fail for ADO. The common format, dd/mm/yyyy, will fail anywhere for days from 1 to 12. Of course, if you store dates as strings - which is a no-no - you will have to adopt. But in Access there is never a reason to store dates as anything else than data type Date.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid any date format issues I find that using the DD MMM yyyy format works accross servers and machines
10 Jan 2016 is more reliable than 10/1/2016 or 1/10/2016

```
strCriteria = "[Order Date] >= #" & Format(Me!txtOrderDateFrom.Value, "dd MMM yyyy") & "# AND [Order Date] <= #" & Format(Me!txtOrderDateTo.Value, dd MMM yyyy") & "# And [Order Amount] >= " & Str(Me!txtSumOfLinePrice.Value) & ""
```

for those who have issue use format(date,"long date")

Comment: This will fail in a non-English environment. Never use localized expressions - as mmm.

Comment: using VBA the mmm will be localised to the international and regional settings.  see http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=315:excel-vba-dates-a-time-format-function-user-defined-date-number-a-string-formats&catid=79&Itemid=475

Comment: Yes, and that's why you should always refrain from using MMM for building SQL strings. They will fail.